# R: Filter correlation matrix on values > and <

Tags: r, filter, correlation

I am programming in R and have a huge correlation matrix. I would like to filter this matrix such that I only have rows and columns containing values >0.7 or <-0.7.
I already tried subset and filter but don't really get what I want. The additional problem is that there are so many row/column names that I do not want to work on them.
Can anybody please help?

eg

```
  1    2  3   4  
1 1    0  0.7 0.6  
2 0    1  0.6 0.6  
3 0.1  0  1   0.8  
4 -0.2 0  0.7 0.9
```

should return

```
  1    3    4   
1 1    0.7  0.6  
3 0.1  1    0.8  
4 -0.2 0.7  0.9
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example?

Comment: The example provided cannot be a correlation matrix since it is not symmetric.

Answer (score 8):

Zero out the diagonal and use `apply(..., 1, any)` to find the rows (and therefore also the columns owing to symmetry) which have values >= threshold.

For testing, if `cc` is the matrix in the question then we have used `cor(cc)` and `threshold = 0.6` instead because `cc` in the question is not a correlation matrix.

```
cc <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0.1, -0.2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.7, 0.6, 1, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9), 4)
cc <- cor(cc)

threshold <- 0.6
cc0 <- cc
diag(cc0) <- 0
ok <- apply(abs(cc0) >= threshold, 1, any)
cc[ok, ok]
```

giving:

```
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.6375997
[2,] -0.6375997  1.0000000
```

The last two lines of code could alternately be replaced with this which gets the coordinates of the entries >= threshold using `which(..., arr = TRUE)`

```
ix <- sort(unique(c(which(abs(cc0) >= threshold, arr = TRUE))))
cc[ix, ix]
```