# Subsetting variable in matrix based on positive correlations to build a composite indicator

Tags: r, subset, correlation, indicator

I am aiming at building a composite indicator. An important step, before proceeding with weighting & aggregation rules, and as described in the [OECD Handbook on Constructing Composite Indicators](http://www.oecd.org/sdd/42495745.pdf#page=34) is to look at **correlations between indicators**.

> Note that there will almost always be some positive correlation between different measures of the same aggregate. Thus, a rule of thumb should be introduced to define a threshold beyond which the correlation is a symptom of double counting.

In order to proceed with this (*i.e. selecting only positively indicators with a certain correlation threshold*), I have tried the following - with the example below

```
df <- data.frame(
  indic1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
  indic2 = c(0.28571, 0.5714285, 0.4285714, 0.142857, 0.285714, 1, 0.71428, 0.14285, 0.5714, 0.142, 0, 0.14285, 0.8571, 0.8571427, 0.4285), 
  indic3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
  indic4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
  indic5 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5), 
  indic6 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
  indic7 = c(0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0), 
  indic8 = c(0, 0, 0.3333, 1, 0.3333, 0.3333, 0.3333, 1, 0, 0.3333, 0.3333, 0.3333, 0, 0, 1), 
  indic9 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
  indic10 = c(0, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 0.2), 
  indic11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
  indic12 = c(0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
  indic13 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), 
  indic14 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
  indic15 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), 
  indic16 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), 
  indic17 = c(0.3333, 0.3333, 0.6666, 0, 0.6666, 0.1666, 1, 0.3333, 0.8333, 0.5, 0.1666, 0.5, 0, 0.8333, 0.1666), 
  indic18 = c(0.857142, 0.428571, 0.85714, 0.142857, 0.714285, 0.5714, 0.714285, 0, 0.42857, 0.857142, 0, 0, 1, 0.2857, 0), 
  row.names = c("Area1", "Area2", "Area3", "Area4", "Area5", "Area6", "Area7", "Area8", "Area9", "Area10", "Area11", "Area12", "Area13", "Area14", "Area15"))

## now correlation matrix
    corr.matrix <- cor(df, method = "pearson",  use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

## Visualization with ggplot  
  ggcorrplot(corr.matrix ,
                        method = "circle",
                        hc.order = TRUE,
                        type = "upper")
```

[image]

Next is to subset, the correlation matrix for a specific threshold (following the example here: [R: Filter correlation matrix on values > and <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592683/r-filter-correlation-matrix-on-values-and)

So the code would be:

```
corr.matrix0 <- corr.matrix
diag(corr.matrix0) <- 0

##set up threshold
threshold <- 0.6

## Now subsetting but here without absolute value
#ok <- apply(abs(corr.matrix0) >= threshold, 1, any)
ok <- apply( corr.matrix0 >= threshold, 1, any)

## or
# ok <- sort(unique( c(which(abs(corr.matrix0) >= threshold, arr = TRUE))))
# ok <- sort(unique( c(which(corr.matrix0 >= threshold, arr = TRUE))))

corr.matrixnew <-  corr.matrix[ok, ok]
ggcorrplot(corr.matrixnew ,
           method = "circle",
           hc.order = TRUE,
           type = "upper")
```

But as seen in the results this did not work out... as I can still see some negative correlations...
[image]

I guess there should be an optimization process based on the correlation matrix - like a kind of *lasso* to do that?

Anyone having a script for this ? Or maybe I am missing something..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the easiest option is to do it with `findCorrelation` from `caret`. It is created for exactly this situation.

```
# do it with cart
library(caret)
to_remove <- findCorrelation(corr.matrix, cutoff = threshold)

corr.matrix_2 <- cor(df[, -to_remove], method = "pearson",  use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

ggcorrplot(corr.matrix_2 ,
           method = "circle",
           hc.order = TRUE,
           type = "upper")
```

[image]

Alternatively you can do it manually with just base R:

```
# do it manually
df2 <- as.data.frame(corr.matrix)
df2[lower.tri(corr.matrix, diag = TRUE)] <- NA

to_remove_2 <- (which(sapply(df2,function(x) any(abs(x) > threshold, na.rm = TRUE))))

corr.matrix_3 <- cor(df[, -to_remove_2], method = "pearson",  use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

ggcorrplot(corr.matrix_3 ,
           method = "circle",
           hc.order = TRUE,
           type = "upper")
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
I might have misunderstood you. I thought you wanted to remove those with correlation > threshold.

But, if you want to keep them and remove others:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(corr.matrix)
diag(df2) <- NA
to_keep <- (which(sapply(df2,function(x) any(x > threshold, na.rm = TRUE))))

corr.matrix_4 <- cor(df[, to_keep], method = "pearson",  use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

ggcorrplot(corr.matrix_4 ,
           method = "circle",
           hc.order = TRUE,
           type = "upper")
```

[image]

This might still have negative correlations because, while pair-wise correlation of variables are high, some of their interactions are negative.

Example:
A to B > 0.6, C to D > 0.6, but A to C < 0

If you want all of them high, it is not a pair-wise correlation...

**EDIT_2:**

> selecting only positively indicators with a certain correlation threshold)

If you just want to do it for plotting purposes: Remove negative numbers 
 (or those below threshold) from correlation matrix and plot it.

```
# corr.matrix_4[corr.matrix_4 <= 0] <- NA
corr.matrix_4[corr.matrix_4 <= threshold] <- NA


library(GGally) 
# Using GGally here as ggcorrplot doesn't handle NAs
# Or do it manually: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-quick-correlation-matrix-heatmap-r-software-and-data-visualization

ggcorr(corr.matrix_4, cor_matrix = corr.matrix_4, labbel = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- though I would like to keep only positive correlation -- in the example if I remove the abs    
to_remove_2 <- (which(sapply(df2,function(x) any(x > threshold, na.rm = TRUE))))          it still keeps some negative correlations... Any hints...

Comment: Dear @jav -- "If you want all of them high, it is not a pair-wise correlation..." --> this is precisely where I believe to be confused -- What could be the other options if not using "pair-wise correlation" ?  How can I remove indicators that have negative interactions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3148607 some kind of copula analysis. But it contradicts your question and your linked OECD handbook. It specifically refers to double counting problem where pairwise correlation of two or more variables are high. It doesn't mean that variable A needs to have high correlation to all variables to be removed (or underweighted), the fact that A and B have high correlation is enough for that.